# What is meaning of calling superview's viewwillappear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
-(void)viewwillAppear
{
[super viewwillAppear:animated];
}
```

What does mean of calling `[super viewwillAppear:animated]` and what happen if we not call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `super` you are calling the base class version of the method. You will see similar call  in `init`, `dealloc`, `viewDidLoad` etc. methods. The reason is in base class's implementation something important may be carried out without which the derived class will not work properly. When you have overridden the method in derived class, you will need to make a call to the base version by using `super`.

The only situation you will not call base class's method by using `super` is when you know that you don't need the tasks carried out by base class, in other words you are overriding completely. This is not the situation with `viewWillAppear:animated` or `viewDidLoad` etc. So we always call super in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

The [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states

> This method is called before the
>   receiver’s view is about to be
>   displayed onscreen and before any
>   animations are configured for showing
>   the view. You can override this method
>   to perform custom tasks associated
>   with presenting the view. For example,
>   you might use this method to change
>   the orientation or style of the status
>   bar to coordinate with the orientation
>   or style of the view being presented.
>   **If you override this method, you must
>   call super at some point in your
>   implementation.**

Answer (score 2):

Apple's documentation for viewWillAppear: just says:

> If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

It will probably lead to some unexpected behavior if you don't call it. Note that 'at some point' means you don't have to call it first.

Comment: Without the call to super, only your custom functionality within the implimentation of your own view controller will be executed. Any functionality higher up in the inheritence hierachy will not be executed. i.e. viewwillAppear:animated: which lies within the UIViewController implimentation will not be executed.

Comment: If a call to super is never made then the superclass method will never be invoked; I think that is obvious. The question however is whether super's implementation of viewWillAppear: is important enough that it warrants the call to super. I think the answer is sometimes it is and sometimes it is not. For example it may be important if you subclass UINavigationController but not UIViewController. To be safe, always use it.